# Laravel 5.2 flash messages not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using **use Flash;** to display my flash messages but they are not showing

```
protected function store(Request $request)
{

   $this->validate($request, [
        'service_name' => 'required'
    ]);

    $service = new Service();
    $service->service_name = $request->input('service_name');
    $service->business_id = Auth::user()->user_id;
    $service->save();

    Flash::message('Service successfully added');

    return redirect('/business/editservices');
    }
```

View code

```
@if (Session::has('flash_notification.message'))
 <div class="alert alert-{{ Session::get('flash_notification.level') }}">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"   aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
   {{ Session::get('flash_notification.message') }}
</div>
  @endif
```

What might be the problem?Please help

Answer (score 2):

If you have a request object just use it to flash:

```
protected function store(Request $request)
{

$this->validate($request, [
    'service_name' => 'required'
]);

$service = new Service();
$service->service_name = $request->input('service_name');
$service->business_id = Auth::user()->user_id;
$service->save();

$request->session()->flash('message', 'Service successfully added');

return redirect('/business/editservices');
}
```

or even esiaer using redirect:

```
return redirect('/business/editservices')->with('message', 'Service successfully added');
```

and then:

```
Session::has('message');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Its working for me:

```
Session::flash('message', 'Your Message');

@if (Session::has('message'))
<div>{!! Session::get('message')!!}</div>
@endif
```